# Java parogram using Queue

Tags: java

I am writing a JAVA program which contains two classes both the classes has two functions, one functions will store map values queue and another function will retrieve the values from queue. and I am calling the two functions one after the other.

Insertion is working fine but the problem occurred while removing from the Queue I used both the methods queue.poll(); and queue.remove(); it is giving last inserted element. Below is my sample code kindly suggest something

```
class One {
   void functionOne(){
   Map<int,String> map = new LinkedHashMap<int,String>();
   Two obj2 = new Two(); 
   for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
     map.put(i,"one");
     obj2.pushData(map)
   }
}
class Two {
   Queue queue = new LinkedList();
   void pushData(Map<int,String> map) {
      queue.add(map);
   }
   void functionTwo() {
             System.out.println("Data:"+queue.size());
       while(queue.size()>0) {
         System.out.println("Data:"+queue.poll());
 // Here I have also used queue.remove();
       }
   }
}
class Three {
   public static void main() {
   One one = new One();
   Two two = new Two();
one.functionOne();
two.functionTwo();

   }
}
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Could you post your actual code?

Comment: Just seeing the above code, it is clear that you haven't typed it in IDE. There are some very basic mistakes. Please try something from your end and then post.

Comment: You do realise that you're pushing the same instance of the `Map` to your queue each time?  You loop is simply adding new data to the `Map`...try create a new `Map` instead you loop (where you call `pushData`)

Comment: Object of class Two in actual program I created it in constructor

Comment: @vikingsteve I would "guess" `obj2` is an instance of `Two` seen as it "seems" to have a `pushData` method...but since it doesn't resemble any valid Java code, that's all guess work..

Comment: If the "obj2" object is instantiated in the constructor of the "One" class method invoked on the "Three" class is on a different instance.

Comment: Code you provided is no more working. provide actual code.

Comment: Hi @vikingsteve it is sample code, I am getting problem while removing the map values from queue I had checked the insertion with println statement it is working fine, but removing it is giving last element and and the size of the queue is also getting correct

Comment: Down voting does not make any sense...as I told you that, the above code is sample code as I cant post my entire code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this piece of code...

```
Map<int,String> map = new LinkedHashMap<int,String>();
Two obj2 = new Two(); 
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
  map.put(i,"one");
  obj2.pushData(map)
}
```

You create an instance of `Map`, you then loop 10 times, adding a new value into the `Map`.  On each iteration, you "push" this, single, instance of the `Map` to the queue...

So at the end, you have a queue which has ten references to the same `Map`...?

```
Data:10
Data:{0=one, 1=one, 2=one, 3=one, 4=one, 5=one, 6=one, 7=one, 8=one, 9=one}
Data:{0=one, 1=one, 2=one, 3=one, 4=one, 5=one, 6=one, 7=one, 8=one, 9=one}
Data:{0=one, 1=one, 2=one, 3=one, 4=one, 5=one, 6=one, 7=one, 8=one, 9=one}
Data:{0=one, 1=one, 2=one, 3=one, 4=one, 5=one, 6=one, 7=one, 8=one, 9=one}
Data:{0=one, 1=one, 2=one, 3=one, 4=one, 5=one, 6=one, 7=one, 8=one, 9=one}
Data:{0=one, 1=one, 2=one, 3=one, 4=one, 5=one, 6=one, 7=one, 8=one, 9=one}
Data:{0=one, 1=one, 2=one, 3=one, 4=one, 5=one, 6=one, 7=one, 8=one, 9=one}
Data:{0=one, 1=one, 2=one, 3=one, 4=one, 5=one, 6=one, 7=one, 8=one, 9=one}
Data:{0=one, 1=one, 2=one, 3=one, 4=one, 5=one, 6=one, 7=one, 8=one, 9=one}
Data:{0=one, 1=one, 2=one, 3=one, 4=one, 5=one, 6=one, 7=one, 8=one, 9=one}
```

Try using something more like...

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
  Map<int,String> map = new LinkedHashMap<int,String>();
  map.put(i,"one");
  obj2.pushData(map)
}
```

Which prints out...

```
Data:10
Data:{0=one}
Data:{1=one}
Data:{2=one}
Data:{3=one}
Data:{4=one}
Data:{5=one}
Data:{6=one}
Data:{7=one}
Data:{8=one}
Data:{9=one}
```

Also, make sure that the instance of `Two` which you are calling `pushData` on is the same instance you are calling `functionTwo` on ;)

This is all based on the assumptions made trying to fix you code to look something like...

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Queue;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        One one = new One();
        Two two = new Two();
        one.functionOne(two);
        two.functionTwo();

    }

    static class One {

        public void functionOne(Two obj2) {
                Map<Integer, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                map.put(i, "one");
                obj2.pushData(map);
            }
        }

    }

    static class Two {

        Queue queue = new LinkedList();

        public void pushData(Map<Integer, String> map) {
            queue.add(map);
        }

        public void functionTwo() {
            System.out.println("Data:" + queue.size());
            while (queue.size() > 0) {
                System.out.println("Data:" + queue.poll());
                // Here I have also used queue.remove();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank You so............ much for understanding the actual problem and and the above code is working fine

Comment: Well, it was all guess work ;) Don't forget, a runnable example with expected output goes a long way ;)

Comment: Any way next time onwards I will place the sample code after testing and with expected output